# How do I clone/fork a remote git repository to my own git repository?

Tags: git, github

I am (obviously) new to git. Here is my scenario.
I have a local git repository (server that I maintain) setup for my project. I want to create create a sub-directory e.g. oss-project under my repository. And I want to get (copy) a project on github into that directory. I need to be able to:
1. maintain the commit history on the github project into my repository as well.
2. selectively pull any updates to the oss-project on github in future.

could you advise, what steps do i need to take to achive that?

```
git clone http://my-local-repo/my-project.git
cd my-project
md oss-project
cd oss-project
// How do i proceed ? git clone / fork the oss-project??
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the oss-project submodule in the oss-project subfolder:

```
git submodule add git@github:user/oss-project.git oss-project
```

Assuming you have SSH access to oss-project. If not, use a http/git URL for read-only access.

Later if you want to use the newest version of oss-project:

```
cd oss-project
git checkout master
git pull origin master
cd ..
git add oss-project
git commit
```

Monsters ahead: git submodules are hard to remove.

Comment: Thank you, your answers pointed me in right direction. I ened ed up using read-tree describe on this page https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge.

Comment: Very good idea. Subtree merges are scarier at the beginning, but work much better on the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use [Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) or you can [look at some alternatives](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/).